# Passbook couldn't connect to development web service

Tags: ios, web-services, passbook

I'm creating my own Passbook Web Service, in order to register and update passes created by my server. When I add to the Pass information inside the pass.json the `webServiceURL` and the `authenticationToken` attributes, the pass is displayed but not added to the iOS Passbook App. Given I'm still in development I don't have a https with SSL server, but a plain http one:

```
http://192.168.1.100:8080/PassbookDelivery
```

Does the device and/or the protocol inside the Web Service need some special change in order to accept the pass produced by my server? Does the authenticationToken have any restriction, like string length, cipher or content?

NOTE: I already use the format URL for registering the device for updates, as detailed in the [Passbook web service specification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html), which is (POST)

```
http://192.168.1.100:8080/PassbookDelivery/v1/devices/_deviceLibraryIdentifier_/registrations/_passTypeIdentifier_/_serialNumber_
```

but it doesn't get any call from the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: go to Settings > Developer, scroll down to PASSKIT TESTING and toggle "Allow HTTP Services".

Comment: Thanks!! You're right, once the device is connected, the "Developer" tab appeared on settings and with that change you said my web service was successfully called